# What to use: Primary Key, Foreign Key or UNIQUE?

Tags: oracle, database-design

So I tried to upload the DER scheme with the TABLE already created but it seems I need to level up, so.

I'm trying to figure out which (PK/FK/UQ)CONSTRAINT to use on the rows. The DER scheme didn't point that out and since I'm a complete dummy on SQL I am back with the question:

```
CREATE TABLE autor
(
   aut_matricula       NUMBER (6),
   aut_nome            VARCHAR2 (50) CONSTRAINT autor_aut_nome NOT NULL,
   aut_cpf             NUMBER (11) CONSTRAINT autor_aut_cpf_nn NOT NULL,
   aut_dtnasc          DATE CONSTRAINT autor_aut_dtnasc_nn NOT NULL,
   aut_nacionalidade   VARCHAR2 (50)
                          CONSTRAINT autor_aut_nacionalidade_nn NOT NULL
);    

CREATE TABLE livro
(
   liv_codigo       NUMBER (6) CONSTRAINT livro_liv_codigo_nn NOT NULL,
   liv_titulo       VARCHAR2 (50) CONSTRAINT livro_liv_titulo_nn NOT NULL,
   liv_preco        NUMBER (5, 2) CONSTRAINT livro_liv_preco_nn NOT NULL,
   liv_lancamento   DATE CONSTRAINT livro_liv_lancamento_nn NOT NULL,
   edi_codigo       NUMBER (6) CONSTRAINT livro_edi_codigo_nn NOT NULL,
   ass_sigla        CHAR (3) CONSTRAINT livro_ass_sigla_nn NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE escreve
(
   liv_codigo      NUMBER (1) CONSTRAINT escreve_liv_codigo_nn NOT NULL,
   aut_matricula   NUMBER (1) CONSTRAINT escreve_aut_matricula_nn NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE assunto
(
   ass_sigla       CHAR (3) CONSTRAINT assunto_ass_sigla_nn NOT NULL,
   ass_descricao   VARCHAR2 (50) CONSTRAINT assunto_ass_descricao_nn NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE editora
(
   edi_codigo   NUMBER (1) CONSTRAINT editora_edi_codigo_nn NOT NULL,
   edi_nome     VARCHAR2 (50) CONSTRAINT editora_edi_nome_nn NOT NULL
);
```

These are the TABLES that needs to be created, who's the PRIMARY KEY and who's FOREIGN REFERENCES to? Or should one of them be UNIQUE?

Edit: I linked the images on the comments.

Comment: https://imgur.com/YMzFQnE

Comment: https://imgur.com/2BHlHPw

Comment: Hi. Please read & act on [mcve]. Please clarify via post edits, not comments. Please [use text, not images/links, for text (including code, tables & ERDs)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use an image only for convenience to supplement text and/or for what cannot be given in text. And never give a diagram without a legend/key. Use edit functions to inline, not link, if you have the rep--make your post self-contained. What did you learn from reading design & SQL references & [so] re PKs etc? Please see the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Comment: @philipxy I'll keep that in mind next time I have a question, sorry for the inconvenience. I'll make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it, simply by looking at column names (which are rather self-descriptive). I've also commented out pieces of your code which became superfluous or wrong (such as datatypes in the ESCREVE table).

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE assunto
  2  (
  3     ass_sigla       CHAR (3) CONSTRAINT pk_ass PRIMARY KEY,
  4     -- removed by LF assunto_ass_sigla_nn NOT NULL
  5     ass_descricao   VARCHAR2 (50) CONSTRAINT assunto_ass_descricao_nn NOT NULL
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE editora
  2  (
  3     edi_codigo   NUMBER (1) CONSTRAINT pk_editora PRIMARY KEY,
  4     -- removed by LF editora_edi_codigo_nn NOT NULL
  5     edi_nome     VARCHAR2 (50) CONSTRAINT editora_edi_nome_nn NOT NULL
  6  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE autor
  2  (
  3     aut_matricula       NUMBER (6) CONSTRAINT pk_aut PRIMARY KEY,
  4     aut_nome            VARCHAR2 (50) CONSTRAINT autor_aut_nome NOT NULL,
  5     aut_cpf             NUMBER (11) CONSTRAINT autor_aut_cpf_nn NOT NULL,
  6     aut_dtnasc          DATE CONSTRAINT autor_aut_dtnasc_nn NOT NULL,
  7     aut_nacionalidade   VARCHAR2 (50)
  8                            CONSTRAINT autor_aut_nacionalidade_nn NOT NULL
  9  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE livro
  2  (
  3     liv_codigo       NUMBER (6) CONSTRAINT pk_liv PRIMARY KEY,
  4     -- removed by LF livro_liv_codigo_nn NOT NULL,
  5     liv_titulo       VARCHAR2 (50) CONSTRAINT livro_liv_titulo_nn NOT NULL,
  6     liv_preco        NUMBER (5, 2) CONSTRAINT livro_liv_preco_nn NOT NULL,
  7     liv_lancamento   DATE CONSTRAINT livro_liv_lancamento_nn NOT NULL,
  8     edi_codigo       NUMBER (6)
  9                         CONSTRAINT fk_liv_edi REFERENCES editora (edi_codigo)
 10                         NOT NULL,
 11     -- removed by LF livro_edi_codigo_nn NOT NULL
 12     ass_sigla        CHAR (3)
 13                         CONSTRAINT fk_liv_ass REFERENCES assunto (ass_sigla)
 14                         NOT NULL
 15  -- removed by LFlivro_ass_sigla_nn NOT NULL
 16  );

Table created.

SQL>
SQL> CREATE TABLE escreve
  2  (
  3     liv_codigo      NUMBER (6)
  4                        CONSTRAINT fk_esc_liv REFERENCES livro (liv_codigo),
  5     -- removed by LF NUMBER (1) CONSTRAINT  escreve_liv_codigo_nn NOT NULL,
  6     aut_matricula   NUMBER (6)
  7                        CONSTRAINT fk_esc_aut REFERENCES autor (aut_matricula),
  8     -- removed by LF NUMBER (1) CONSTRAINT escreve_aut_matricula_nn NOT NULL
  9     CONSTRAINT pk_esc PRIMARY KEY (liv_codigo, aut_matricula)
 10  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

Comment: I was always curious about the way you code, the first time you answered my question and still on my mind. My teacher is giving me instructions about what is good or isn't to write down on a code and the other day I saw that you don't code like my teacher does but it works fine and much better than his way. I was wondering if there's a cheat sheet where you could get shortcuts without constraint errors like you do with less "coding", you don't finish your PK with parenthesis before and after and neither you do follow the "rules" of row names as such in "ch_nra_2k".

Comment: how do you do it? I mean, was that all trial and error until you got there? Is there a book where I can learn that technique? How many years have you been coding?

Comment: As usual, there are different ways to get from A to B. Your teacher (which means: you, as students) does that one way. I did it another. Someone else's approach might be different from these two. We all, however, must follow certain rules - syntax. As of naming conventions (as you've said, "ch_nra_2k") - all there is are *suggestions*; one company might do it one way, we'll do it another. At the end, it doesn't matter much, as long as you know what it is. Although you can name a constraint as "oiajsf", it is stupid to do so. Oracle won't complain, but your colleagues might.

Comment: I didn't do anything by *trial and error* while answering your question. I just *know* what to do in order to make it work and make sense. I don't know whether there are any "cheat sheets"; I usually call these "documentation". And - as you spotted well - it takes time. I've been coding (in Oracle) for almost 25 years, and I still learn something new every day. I enjoy participating discussions on forums (Stack Overflow included, recently). Trying to solve other members' problems helps in developing me, as an Oracle developer. And still, there are MANY programmers far better than me.

Comment: I get it, everybody is different so the coding must be equivalent to the person behind the screen. But I was really curious how did you get to the "ch_nra_2k" if that's not what is written physically, I mean, technically that doesn't match the names of the table rows created, so my question is how do you know that "nra_2k" is going to be found when the check is executed? What those characters mean to the Oracle Dev?

Comment: I wasn't referring to your resolutions of the table problem... It was more like what goes in your mind when you to try to rearrange the tables? Do you think about the order itself or do you come up with a story and then you create them? And yes I noticed that you must be coding in Oracle for a long time... And sure there might be MANY programmers better than you but they didn't ou couldn't help me understand the problem. So, right now you became an inspiration to me.

Comment: "ch_nra_2k": **CH** stands for "check constraint" (as FK stands for foreign key constraint, PK for primary key constraint, and so forth). **NRA** stands for columnn name (NR_Anoletivo). **2K** stands for "year 2000" (as we've been dealing with it).